# How to extract the number of feet from an NBA event log

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, stringr

So I have data for home and away play descriptions of an NBA play by play data log. I would like to extract the shot distance from these two columns.

| HomePlayDescription | AwayPlayDescription |
| --- | --- |
| MISS Davis 20' Jump Shot | *NA* |
| Holiday BLOCK (1 BLK) | MISS Payton 2' Layup |

The desired output in this case is c(20,2)

I have tried parse_number from tidyr but this will give the vector c(20,1), as the function does not know I only want the distance extracted.

Comment: `parse_number` is from `readr`. :-)

Comment: How is distance defined?

Comment: Is the tabular format of the data relevant to your parsing, or are you just applying the RegExp to the individual strings extracted from the table cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use `acrosse` and `parse_number` to get the numbers only in the whole dataframe
2. use `lead` to bring `AwayPlayDescription` to same row as `HomePlayDescription`
3. `paste` them together
4. `slice` the second row (this could be done within groups for many groups.
5. `pull` distance:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), parse_number)) %>% 
    mutate(AwayPlayDescription = lead(AwayPlayDescription)) %>% 
    mutate(distance = paste(HomePlayDescription, AwayPlayDescription, sep = ",")) %>% 
    slice(-2) %>% 
    pull(distance)
```

```
[1] "20,2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pattern like this to extract the distance from a string:

```
(?:MISS|MADE)\b\w+(\d{1,2})'[\w\b]+
```